# Paperclip Rails 4 Simple Form image upload error in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

Trying to load paperclip to my Recipe model.  I've used paperclip before and installed imagemagick but have not seen this error before.  Has anyone encountered this before?

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@recipe, htm l: {:multipart => true, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |recipe_form| %>
  <%= recipe_form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

My model

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/ }
end
```

The form shows up fine and the file appears to load.  On submit, I receive the error

```
undefined method `to_hash' for #Object:0x007f946b652af0>
```

In my recipe's controller it highlights this line as the error

RecipesController#create  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb, line 58

```
def create
   @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
end
```

My controller also has

```
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:avatar, :name, :characteristic_ids => [])
end
```

Also, ran the migration to attach an avatar to the Recipe

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :recipes do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :recipes, :avatar
  end
end
```

If I refresh the screen I then receive a

```
Internal Server Error

undefined method `[]' for #<Object:0x007f946b652af0>
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22) at localhost:3000
```

NOTE:

The recipe_params in my Recipes Create method are

```
{"avatar"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88e4e2e900
   @content_type="image/jpeg",
   @headers=
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"recipe[avatar]\"; filename=\"fat_horse.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
   @original_filename="fat_horse.jpg",
   @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140701-93587-xn8gg3>>,
 "name"=>"dfdasfd",
 "characteristic_ids"=>[2, 17, 32, 36, 54, 55, 76, 84]}
```

And the error when I run pry in my console on Recipe.new(recipe_params) is

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/7110cbad451851f4d78f4f5a746bb61020140701-93587-1jfe23k.jpg'
sh: file: command not found
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_hash' for #<Object:0x007f88e34de9a0>
from /Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/climate_control-0.0.3/lib/climate_control/modifier.rb:62:in `clone_environment'
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any other errors / exceptions in the log? I looks like your system is set up correctly; perhaps the issue is db related or something?

Comment: @RichPeck yes, I added a note to the question with more on the error.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're specifying `:characteristic_ids => []` instead of just declaring the key (`:characteristic_ids`)?

Comment: @mmichael that allows for multiple id's to be sent through permitted params.

Comment: @Finneran interesting, I wasn't aware you needed to explicitly state it. I thought you just needed to define the input in the form (i.e. `name="characteristic_ids[]"`).

Comment: @mmichael I believe in Rails 4 you need to specify that the permitted params is an array. https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

params.permit(:id => [])